# CURL - locally vs webserver

Tags: php, curl

I have a script which works just fine locally but when i try to run it on a webserver it fails to run and the timelimit is exceeded.

I have a list of categories in an array whose keys are their ids and the values are the names. Foreach category i call a curl command to get all the products via external api. Setting of that CURL call are as follows:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {

        $url_get_products = "http://luceed.euromdenis.hr:8081/datasnap/rest/artikli/GrupaArtikla/".$key;
        $cp = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_URL, $url_get_products);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_error($cp);

        $product_result = curl_exec($cp);
        curl_close($cp);

        $data = json_decode($product_result, TRUE);
```

From there array is initialized with the needed part of the $data variable

```
$arr_temp = $data['result'][0]['artikli'];
```

Then a loop is enter in which i check every product

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_temp); $i++) {
```

Since the api database is poorly organised there is no images of products there and therefore i have to use another url to get the images with the proper id.

Image url looks something like this:

```
random_url.com/slike/'.$product_id.'.jpg
```

So i'm traversing all the products within the category and checking if there is an image existing with the given url with this function

```
function isUrlExist($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $status;
}
```

If there is an image the product is added to an array from which csv file is generated later on.

Locally image check is done instantaneouslly but when i run it on server side it takes forever and when i have 50-60 categories to check where every category has couple of hundreds of products the time limit is easily exceeded and the script is stopped.

Is there any solution to this, maybe with some curl options?

P.S. This is the info i got when i echoed the errors and data from curl_info

```
Failed to connect to web-domain-name.com port 80: Connection timed out<br/>
```

Comment: try to add in the loop : set_time_limit ( 300 );

Comment: within the nested loop?

Comment: try just after :  foreach ($categories as $key => $value) { set_time_limit ( 300 ); ......}

Comment: Still nothing changes

Comment: This is the error message you get? sure that you want to connect to `web-domain-name.com` on port `80` ? otherwhise you should provide the correct credentials to the server you want to connect. Have you checked the addresses your script uses?

Comment: I just substituted the url since i'm not comfortable with publicaly sharing it and I didn't think it's that important to you guy. My scripts are using propper addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in that external server banned ip from which it was calling the script because of the number of requests. The solution was that after ban was dismissed i used curl only once to get all the images into a file then checking if the url is valid instead of calling curl for every single product. It makes more sense this way anyways